# Material breaking underneath its breaking point (due to repeated load)

Tags: material-science, metals

I'm trying to recall some fact that I learned in my college materials science class, where we learned concepts like stress vs. strain.

I remember that materials like metal have a breaking point, and if an applied stress produces a force higher than the breaking point, the metal will break. Or something like that.

Now, I distinctly remember my professor showing some real-world engineering failure where a metal was used in a structure (in an airplane or bridge), and it broke even through the stress never went above the breaking point. Rather, the metal broke due to repeated use of the structure. What is this principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to elastic fatigue. Here's [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_fatigue).

Answer (score 0):

Its called a fatigue failure. After many cycles of use, the material fails because minute imperfections propagate and get larger until failure occurs. This can happen well below the strength of the material.

Comment: Perhaps, is that the same principle as spring fatigue due to constant force? It will be nice to know the **physical theory microscopically** behind it.